# How to get EC2 instance costs via AWS Billing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tags, billing

I am trying to differentiate costs among my AWS EC2 instances.

I've tried everything mentioned via forums and AWS, I've created Tags to ID each EC2 instance, and I still cannot seem to get billing report telling me how much each instance is accumulating cost wise.  They are all lumped together.

I created and enabled a tag for each, but still Cost Explorer is virtually useless, and only chunks these costs into instance types.

One other similar solution mentioned to create separate AWS accounts for each customer/client?  Which in my case,  is too late, if this is the only way to differentiate costs among the running EC2 instances.

Comment: Are you saying each of your EC2 instance has a unique tag, but you can't see the billing broken up by those tags? Or are you saying you have several instances with the same tag, and want to see that broken up by instance ID in addition to the tag?

Comment: I have 2 separate EC2 instances, each with a unique tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to manually enable cost allocation tags in the console.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/activating-tags.html

**To activate your tags**

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Billing and Cost Management console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/.
2. In the navigation pane, choose Cost Allocation Tags.
3. Select the tags that you want to activate.
4. Choose Activate.

Good luck!

Comment: I believe I've tried this walk thru, and have enabled the cost allocation tags in the console,  and it mentioned to give it about 24 hours.  I remember coming the next day and checking the Billing report Cost Explorer, and got nothing... But I just now checked and now see a legible breakdown.  Thanks